# "The entity type 'JobConceptTranslationEntity' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have two table which are **JobConcept** and **JobConceptTranslation**. So, both of them have relation like this:

```
[Table("JobConcept")]
public class JobConceptEntity : BaseEntity, IHasKey<Guid> {
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<JobConceptTranslationEntity> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
[Table("JobConceptTranslations")]
public class JobConceptTranslationEntity : TranslationEntity {
  [ForeignKey(nameof(JobConceptId))]
  public Guid JobConceptId { get; set; }

  public virtual JobConceptEntity JobConcept { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Anyway, I've already intented the primary key like this on OnModelCreating:

modelBuilder.Entity().HasKey(x => new { x.JobConceptId, x.LanguageCode });

But it gives this error unfortunaly, **"The entity type 'JobConceptTranslationEntity' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.",](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.%22,)**

I'tried to add `public Guid? Id {get;set;}` with [Key] data annotation and tried  new migra for database but then it gives **"JobConceptTranslations' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed""** error

So, could you help me about this, because I've been realy get stuck about it.

Comment: Use `[ForeignKey(nameof(JobConceptEntity))]` instead of `[ForeignKey(nameof(JobConceptId))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `[ForeignKey(xxx)]` attribute on the foreign key property in the dependent class, You should pass the name of the navigation property, So here you should use `[ForeignKey(nameof(JobConceptEntity))]`.

But when you use `[ForeignKey(xxx)]` attribute On the navigation property in the dependent class, passing the name of the foreign key property:

```
[ForeignKey("JobConceptId")]
public virtual JobConceptEntity JobConcept { get; set; }
```

More details you can refer to [link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute).